# ломается кодировка csv файла при открытии в Excel. csv записан с помощью Python3 pandas

Tags: python, pandas, excel, csv

```
DataFrame(new_df).to_csv(my, mode='w', index=False, sep=';' encoding='utf-8')
```

При чтении csv появляются кракозябры. В pycharm файл открывается нормально и кириллица как кириллица, пишет, что кодировка записанного файла utf-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так у `Excel` родная для `MS Windows` кодировка: `cp1251`, записывайте файл в этой кодировке, если хотите открывать потом `Excel`-ем.

```
encoding='cp1251'
```

Comment: Помогло, благодарю